# ffmpeg overlay time code with time zone offset

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to generate a live playout from ffmpeg that overlays time code but with a specific time zone (or simple hour-based offset) applied. I have found success in generating time code overlays with both gmtime and localtime filters, however, I have not been able to crack the context necessary for offsetting that time by *n* number of hours. The following is a quick and dirty example of what I have been able to achieve thus far:

```
ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -i image.png -vf drawtext="fontsize=96: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.75: boxborderw=5: fontcolor=white: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2: text='%{localtime\:%H\\\\\:%M\\\\\:%S}'" -r 10 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -an -f mpegts udp://239.0.0.1:50000

ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -i image.png -vf drawtext="fontsize=96: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.75: boxborderw=5: fontcolor=white: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2: text='%{gmtime\:%H\\\\\:%M\\\\\:%S}'" -r 10 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -an -f mpegts udp://239.0.0.1:50000
```

The issue here is that I need to set the time being overlayed to a specific time zone (PST) or to an offset of -3 hours from the time zone my server is located.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Use the pts function with a timestamp offset

Comment: You can use `%T` instead of `%H\\\\\:%M\\\\\:%S`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your suggestions! While I was admittedly hoping for a solution that is slightly less complex (having to manually define a start time is going to be only a very small burden compared to just offsetting automatically by an hour or two with my previous methods), using Gyan's tip to go with PTS and a defined UTC timestamp gets me to where I need to go:

```
ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -i image.png -vf drawtext="fontsize=96: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.75: boxborderw=5: fontcolor=white: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2: text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1575561900}'" -r 10 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -an -f mpegts udp://239.0.0.1:50000
```

For those who may want to use this as future reference, the above will print an overlay time code starting at '2019-12-05 04:05:00' (date and approx time of this post). To quickly find the Epoch time required for accurate offset, I used [this](https://www.epochconverter.com) site.