# ffmpeg overlay timestamp with timezone offset without using Epoch

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

Currently trying to overlay a very accurate timestamp on top of a video Mosaic, but I've run into an issue where the only printable real time timestamp is UTC.

A similar question has been asked 2 years ago here [ffmpeg overlay time code with time zone offset](https://superuser.com/questions/1507728/ffmpeg-overlay-time-code-with-time-zone-offset) but it's not useful for my case, unless I somehow find a way to input a real time Epoch code with a 2 hour advance.

The snipped of code I'm using is:

```
drawtext=font=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Comic_Sans_MS.ttf:fontsize=60:box=1:boxcolor=yellow@0.6:fontcolor=magenta:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text='%{gmtime\:%H\\\\\:%M\\\\\:%S}'[time];\
```

I was hoping it was just a matter of replacing `%H` with `%H+2` or `%(H+2)` but it's sadly not as simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy solution and I can't believe it took me this long to figure out (should have read the official filter documentation). You don't need to use `gmtime` at all, you can just use `localtime`, set the system time to your desired timezone and it just works.

So the command would be:

`drawtext=font=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Comic_Sans_MS.ttf:fontsize=60:box=1:boxcolor=yellow@0.6:fontcolor=magenta:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text='%{localtime\:%T}'[time];`